# finding closest craigslist site for given address

Tags: php, ruby, web-services, geocoding, craigslist

how to map closest craigslist site for a given address(zip)? or I was thinking of making that mapping myself by looking at the list of craigslist sites city-wise/state-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I believe the best solution is to get a list of Craigslist sites/cities, prebuild a mapping of cities to coordinates using some geocoding API ([Tiny Geocoder](http://tinygeocoder.com/) comes to mind but Yahoo and Bing offer good solutions too), and then storing it in a way that makes sort-by-nearest easy (say, [MySQL's geospatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) or [MongoDB's](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing)).